# Android Accessibility Service not running when screen off

Tags: android, service

I have an AccessibilityService that listens to the volume buttons. It works fine but when the screen is off is does not work at all. Is there a setting or something to make it work when the screen is off?

accessibility_service_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:packageNames="com.kewitschka.volumeskiptrack"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="50"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:settingsActivity=""
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    />
```

Manifest.xml

```
...
<service android:name=".MyService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
....
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Log.v(TAG, "***** onInterrupt");
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    Log.v(TAG, "***** onServiceConnected");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
}
Log.v(TAG, "***** button pressed");
}
```

Comment: witch devise you are using for testing, if its a chines device like oppo, vivo then they implement battery optimization witch case this problem